# How to add "tags" in joomla 3.x blog layout

Tags: php, joomla, tags, joomla3.2

I would like to add the article tags in my blog layout in joomla 3.x.
I overwrote the joomla layout files and tried to add the code below in `blog_style_default_item_title.php` as it is in article

```
 <?php if ($params->get('show_tags', 1) && !empty($this->item->tags)) : ?>
    <?php $this->item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->item->tagLayout->render($this->item->tags->itemTags); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but it did not work. I guess variable name is not the good one. Any ideas?

My knowledges in php language are pretty weak but I had a look and tried a few think.

I finaly got something by adding code below in `/com_content/category/blog_items.php`

```
<?php $this->item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'); ?>
<?php echo $this->item->tagLayout->render($this->item->tags->itemTags); ?>
```

but i would like to add "tags" on the title line so in `blog_style_default_item_title.php`file

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Create a shortcut for params.
$params = $displayData->params;
$canEdit = $displayData->params->get('access-edit');
JHtml::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT.'/helpers/html');
JHtml::_('behavior.framework');
?>

<?php if ($params->get('show_title') || $displayData->state == 0 || ($params->get('show_author') && !empty($displayData->author ))) : ?>
    <div class="page-header">


        <?php if ($params->get('show_title')) : ?>
            <h2>essai
                <?php if ($params->get('link_titles') && $params->get('access-view')) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($displayData->slug, $displayData->catid)); ?>">
                    <?php echo $this->escape($displayData->title); ?></a>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <?php echo $this->escape($displayData->title); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </h2>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php $this->item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->item->tagLayout->render($this->item->tags->itemTags); ?>


        <?php if ($displayData->state == 0) : ?>
            <span class="label label-warning"><?php echo JText::_('JUNPUBLISHED'); ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But i have a error???

Answer (score 0):

Here is how they are added to individual weblinks

```
    <?php $tagsData = $item->tags->getItemTags('com_weblinks.weblink', $item->id); ?>
    <?php if ($this->params->get('show_tags', 1)) : ?>
        <?php $this->item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->item->tagLayout->render($tagsData); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

What you would want to do is something similar but for com_content.article  and make sure the $item and $this->params references match what you have.

Comment: My knowledges in php language are pretty weak but I had a look and tried a few things.

I finaly got something by adding code below in `/com_content/category/blog_items.php`
 
`    <?php $this->item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->item->tagLayout->render($this->item->tags->itemTags); ?> 

but i would like to add "tags" on the title line so in `blog_style_default_item_title.php`file

But i have a error???

Comment: Do you see how I created $tagsData?  You ned to do tht.  If you don't have the data there is nothing to render.   You can't copy and paste from the single article layout, you need to get the tags for each item as you go along.   I have no idea what you are doing with that title file.

Comment: Hey, sorry late answer... like I said efore I reached to add tags in blog items body but I'd like in the add them in the "page-header" where there is article. this last one is call by "blog_items.php" via layout 'blog_style_default_item_title.php'.

My design will look like :
<tr><td>Article Title</td><td> Tag</td></tr>

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you try explaining? I thought based on the first line of your question that you were trying to get them in the blog view (especially since they are available in the article view already).  What do you mean by the "page-header"? Can you take a screen shot and put a circle where you mean?  You can put the block of code whereever you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcmfT.png) a picture of the design I would like

And he below the way the page id made of (as i understood it)

in blog_item.php there is this line which call the

```
...
<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.blog_style_default_item_title', $this->item); ?>
....
```

and so in blog_style_default_item_title.php

```
....
<div class="page-header">
<?php if ($params->get('show_title')) : ?>
            <h2>essai
                <?php if ($params->get('link_titles') && $params->get('access-view')) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($displayData->slug, $displayData->catid)); ?>">
                    <?php echo $this->escape($displayData->title); ?></a>
                <?php else : ?>
```

Did I make a mistake??